# MySQL Decimal empty string / null (Meekrodb)

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Plot` (
  `idPlot` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ListPrice` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WebPrice` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BottomPrice` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPlot`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to have values stored an NULL in the decimal fields if an empty string is passed. I can only seem to store 0.00 however.

I'm using Meekrodb to do the update:

```
$db->update('Plot', array(
  'ListPrice' => $one['ListPrice'],
  'BottomPrice' => $one['BottomPrice'],
  'WebPrice' => $one['WebPrice'] 
), "idPlot=%s", $one['idPlot']);
```

My input array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [idPlot] => 6
    [ListPrice] => 99,999.00
    [BottomPrice] => 
    [WebPrice] => 
)
```

Meekro runs:

```
UPDATE `Plot` SET `ListPrice`='99999.00', `BottomPrice`='', `WebPrice`='' WHERE idPlot='6'
```

And I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idPlot] => 6
            [ListPrice] => 99999.00
            [WebPrice] => 0.00
            [BottomPrice] => 0.00
        )

)
```

stored in the database.

Is there any way of making it populate the fields with NULL rather than 0.00???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note the difference between an empty string:

```
$foo = '';
```

... and a `NULL` value:

```
$foo = NULL;
```

The [print_r()](http://php.net/print_r) function does not display the difference; you need to use [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) to accurately dump your variables:

```
$data = array('', NULL);
print_r($data);
var_dump($data);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
)
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  NULL
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to insert the value as NULL without quotations